# How to place Widgets (footer links) side by side in magento2?

Tags: magento2, footer-links

I created 3 widgets, each has one static block with links for the footer.
Now the "position" is kinda messed up, and i want to place each "link block" 
side by side.

[image]

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks alot and have a nice day / evening!

Comment: You do this with css.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, could you paste the whole code here, or in jsbin, so we can help you with the problem? You can use css to display block side by side.

Comment: What do you mean by the whole code?
I created the block and widget in the Admin Panel under "Content-->Pages" and "Content-->Blocks". Where is the location of the code that gets generated?

Comment: Aaa, ok. Well, the only possible way to change position is to change css, in files. If you don't yet have css file, you can create one in 'app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/web/css/source/_extend.less' and there, you can add your css code. Do you know how to use css to style?